# How to repeat a CSS shape horizontally?

Tags: html, css, repeat, css-shapes

I'd like to decorate the bottom of my page with a repeated triangle. The picture shows one triangle, but I want to fill the whole horizontal div.

Screenshot of what I've got so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJA6D.png

```
<div class="container triangle"> </div>

.triangle {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 15px 0 15px;
border-color: #c2cf31 transparent transparent transparent;
background-color: white;
}
```

Is this possible or do I have to use an img as background?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: you cannot add images to the markup using CSS, so yes you need to use a `background-image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a background image in your CSS-

`background:url("http://site.com/img/whatever.svg");`

And then set it to repeat only horizontally-

`background-repeat:repeat-x;`

This means that yes, you do have to use a background image.

You could [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element using jQuery or something but I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: @Lena - Using JQuery for this is a bad idea (and as harley said, not worth it). You should be using CSS for this.

Comment: I'm not going to use jquery. I was just curious what's theoretically possible. It works fine with the background-image: repeat.

Answer (score 1):

```
background-image:url('your image url');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
```

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is to use background images in CSS if they are not being used as links etc. Basically, if you aren't fussed about the SEO on those images. With that in mind, just use some CSS for your image.

```
background-image: url("yoururl/image.jpg") repeat-x;
```

As it has been mentioned you could technically use JQuery's clone method. This is a bad idea. Why add extra things for the page to do when CSS handles it.

Comment: I just wanted to know what's possible. Sure it doesn't make sense for this project, but now I can keep the jquery option in the back of my head. ;-)

Comment: @Lena - Understood. We get a lot of people on here just asking for a solution regardless whether it's a good idea or not so I would prefer to clarify it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to experiment, there's a CSS property that gives you the ability to use an element (your triangle div in this case) as a background image. This property is the `background:element()`.

You can see a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/t9fnh/) in Firefox.

However, this property works only in Mozilla with the `-moz-` prefix but there have been attempts to work in webkit browsers as well. So, hopefully this can be implemented in the future with wider browser support.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitly look into that!

Answer (score 0):

use the img as background and let it repeat.
I have to say that I like background images more instead of the image in the html code.
This is cause people can't copy them easily as the image in the html code

Comment: You mean I should save the triangle as .png instead of the CSS? Is this my only choice?

Comment: No, he means you need to set it as background image. The format of the image is irrelevant.